# Getting permutation box and S-box for AUT64 block cipher

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes, permutation

Want to get 32 bits from 0x8000 address as 8 bytes (perm box)

```
MEM_EXT:00008000                 db 54h
MEM_EXT:00008001                 db 53h, 57h, 20h
MEM_EXT:00008004                 dd 322E3256h, 31332030h, 30303330h, 31313320h, 43432036h
MEM_EXT:00008004                 dd 2F363535h, 20425345h, 865808FAh, 865808FAh, 865808FAh
MEM_EXT:00008004                 dd 865808FAh, 865808FAh, 865808FAh, 865808FAh, 865808FAh
MEM_EXT:00008004                 dd 865808FAh, 865808FAh, 865808FAh, 0FFA735A7h, 962F8E20h
MEM_EXT:00008004                 dd 0DF00F0h, 0DF00FFh, 0AF008Fh, 70002h, 380038h, 0FF000700h
MEM_EXT:00008004                 dd 0, 0, 0
```

Would this be

0x54 0x53 0x57 0x20 0x32 0x2e 0x32 0x56 ???

How to get further 64 bits, after first 32 bits from 0x8000 (S-box)

Weird things is that 64 bits as 16 bytes should contain also 0 somwehere (S-box)

Those should be permutation and S-box key parts

Some more info:

```
ROM:00000000 ; Processor       : c166 [C165]
ROM:00000000 ; Target assembler: Keil A166 Assembler
ROM:00000000 ; Byte sex        : Little endian
```

Anybody with disassembly (IDA) and cryptographic knowledge can help here to get perm box and S-box values?

Maybe this helps to identify them

[image]